# Why isn't the derived class destructor being called?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, declaration, destructor

I was doing some practicing with pointers to derived classes and when I ran the code provided underneath,the output I get is

```
Constructor A
Constructor B
Destructor A
```

Could someone tell me why is B::~B() not getting invoked here?

```
class A {
 public:
  A() { std::cout << "Constructor A\n"; }
  ~A() { std::cout << "Destructor A\n"; }
};

class B : public A {
 public:
  B() { std::cout << "Constructor B\n"; }
  ~B() { std::cout << "Destructor B\n"; }
};

int main() {
  A* a = new B;
  delete a;
}
```

Comment: If a function is not `virtual`, it can't be called via polymorphism. The `B` and `A`'s destructor is not virtual

Comment: Because you are calling `delete` on a `A*`, not a `B*`, and `A*`'s destructor is not `virtual`. The program has undefined behavior as a consequence, since the most-derived type of the object is actually `B`, not `A`.

Comment: The inverse question: [When to use virtual destructors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/461203/when-to-use-virtual-destructors)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The static type of the pointer `a` is `A *`.

```
A* a = new B;
```

So all called member functions using this pointer are searched in the class `A`.

To call the destructor of the dynamic type of the pointer, that is of the class `B`, you need to declare the destructor as `virtual` in class `A`. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {
 public:
  A() { std::cout << "Constructor A\n"; }
  virtual ~A() { std::cout << "Destructor A\n"; }
};

class B : public A {
 public:
  B() { std::cout << "Constructor B\n"; }
  ~B() override { std::cout << "Destructor B\n"; }
};

int main() {
  A* a = new B;
  delete a;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

becuase overriden methods need to be virtual

```
class A{
public:
    A()
    {
        std::cout<<"Constructor A\n";
    }
    virtual ~A()
    {
        std::cout<<"Destructor A\n";
    }
};
class B : public A{
public:
    B()
    {
        std::cout<<"Constructor B\n";
    }
    virtual ~B()
    {
        std::cout<<"Destructor B\n";
    }
};
```

Comment: The second `virtual` is optional, but `override` may be used to prevent mistakes.

Comment: More specifically, *any time* you write a class with the intention that it be subclassed and used in a virtual context (i.e. through a pointer/reference to the base class), the destructor at minimum needs to be virtual, even if it's `virtual ~A() = default`. Otherwise, you'll run into problems when an instance gets `delete`d via a variable with a parent type.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo ... but you _can_ use polymorphism without a `virtual` destructor if the _deleter_ is stored with the object, as it is in a `std::shared_ptr` ([example](https://godbolt.org/z/ddq1aEoxe)).

Comment: So when I get to "delete a;" what happens is I invoke A::~A() because the pointer a doesn't know B::~B() exists,and if I override A::~A() I make it so it searches for the most derived version of the destructor and it runs into B::~B() and after it finished up with it's object A::~A() gets called?

Comment: @YourFBIAgent yes, the clever magic of derived classes only works for virtual methods , other wise c++ just goes "well he told me this was an A object so I will call `A::~`"

Comment: @YourFBIAgent — `delete a;` produces undefined behavior. It is not required to call `A`’s destructor. The rule is that if the code deletes an object of a derived type through a pointer to the base and the base does not have a virtual destructor the behavior is undefined.